# How to disable any whitespace in a input?

Tags: regex, angular

I have the following pattern

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErpxLN

```
/^(!?=.*\d)/
```

it match every time i put a character.

I would like to negate it. (or find another pattern)

The end result would be -> NOT allowing ANY whitespace. So when there is a white space, at any point in the string, the input throw an error

Comment: For not allowing any whitespace your regex should be `^\S*$`

Answer (score -1):

Change your regex to this.

This however allows spaces at the start and at the end of the input.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/
```